# filter binding source or bindinglist with textbox_keypress

Tags: c#, bindingsource, bindinglist

I use winforms and c#.

How can  I filter Binding source or binding list. with a textbox text ?
I meam while I am typing in a textbox my grid is filtering with a %Like method not (=,equal)method.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use delegate for this problem. Some code like bellow

```
        _List = _List.FindAll(
            delegate(MyEntity entity)
            {
                return entity.Title.Contains(TXT_Title.Text);
            }
        );
        Gview.DataSource = _List  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use CollectionViewSource class to enable filtering.

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx)

Comment: As a found. this example is for Wpf I use c#project and win form.. is there any solution?