# How to reset bindingsource filter to nothing

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, bindingsource, bindinglist

Using `BindingSource` on LINQ to SQL, and having implemented a `BindingList` in my project, I have to use a `Textbox` to filter rows in a `DataGridView`, so when I delete the textbox content, Filter should be reset to nothing.

My code is as follows:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
{
    productBindingSource.Filter = null;
}
else
{
    productBindingSource.Filter = "ProductName = '" + textBox1.Text +"'";
    //productBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
}
productDataGridView.DataSource = productBindingSource;
```

But this does nothing, any idea, please?

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0) {
  productBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
} else {
  productBindingSource.Filter = "ProductName = '" + textBox1.Text +"'";
}

// productDataGridView.DataSource = productBindingSource;
```

The DataGridView shouldn't need to be DataSourced again if it's already using productBindingSource.

Comment: This also doesn't work, I have already tested it. Please see the code line on comment in my question

Comment: @AlphaBird Not sure what you mean by "see the code line on comment in my question"?  Is your productBindingSource coming from a BindingList<>?

Comment: In my question you can find this: //productBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
 means that I have already tried RemoveFilter. And Yes I have passed a BindingList to my productBindingSource which is already working for the "Find" method.

Comment: @AlphaBird Hmm, don't know if a filter would work on a BindingList.  The code I posted works on a DataTable.

Comment: Tried also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532928/filter-binding-source-or-bindinglist-with-textbox-keypress?rq=1), but FindAll is not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx

as shown there the `bindingsource.Filter` is a string value. And default is null, so just do this:

```
productBindingSource.Filter = null;
```

its possible though that you have to do something to update your UI but usually the bindingSource takes care of that itself.

Comment: This doesn't work, your link provide code for dataset type data sources. Please take a look at my initial question update.

Comment: what happens if do this `productBindingSource.Filter = "";`

Comment: Nothing, because Filter doesn't work directly for the bindingSource control, it is necessary to implement a BindingList  in the project and using IEnumerable to reach that purpose, please [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691797/how-do-i-position-a-datagridview-to-the-searched-text-input/11701585#11701585) to know how to implement a BindingList in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "Find" method cannot be used directly with BindingList, but fortunately there is an alternative, using IEnumerable. After Implementing a BindingList in the project, I can filter a bound datagridview using the next code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var qry = (from p in dc.Products
                   select p).ToList();
        BindingList<Product> list = new BindingList<Product>(qry);
        IEnumerable<Product> selection = list.Where(m => m.ProductName.Contains(textBox1.Text) == true);
        productBindingSource.DataSource = selection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you test if textbox is empty in TextChanged event. 
Maybe your method is not being called when Text length = 0.
I don't remember exactly why but i experienced this case before.

If you are using a BindingList you wrote, provide code.
RemoveFilter, setting Filter to null or empty string has always worked for me.