# DataGridView.DefaultView clear filter

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I automatically or by button clear the filter applied ?

I use the following code to filter a `DataGridView` from `frPlanMain` (Form 1) from Form 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    public partial class SearchWindow : Form
    {
        public frPlanMain refTofrPlanMain;

        public SearchWindow(frPlanMain f) //<<Edit made here 
        {
            refTofrPlanMain = f;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SearchButtonW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                (refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Vodic = '{0}'", searchTBoxW.Text);
                for (int i = refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow item = refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows[i];
                    if (item.Visible)
                    {
                        refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                        break;                      
                    }
                //
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You asked me before on this on how to remove data, that isn't filtering. Now you want the data back? This is going to need a bit more of a code change...

Comment: Well, thank you again for taking a interest. After i deleted the row selected i want to remove the filter and see the whole DataSource but without the removed row.

Comment: Ah, ok misunderstood, taking a look

Comment: This is aimed to be a checking program so when i scan a barcode the program to filter, the code scaned, remove the data, restore the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    public partial class SearchWindow : Form
    {
        public frPlanMain refTofrPlanMain;

        public SearchWindow(frPlanMain f) //<<Edit made here 
        {
            refTofrPlanMain = f;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SearchButtonW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Vodic = '{0}'", searchTBoxW.Text);
            for (int i = refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                DataGridViewRow item = refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows[i];
                if (item.Visible)
                {
                    refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;                      
                }
            }
        }
        private void clearFilter_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
            (refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = null;            
        }
    }
}
```

See here: [How to reset bindingsource filter to nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764574/how-to-reset-bindingsource-filter-to-nothing)

Comment: Umm, regarding to the code above where should i place it ?

Comment: Updated the code as requested, you need to create a button and add to the onClick event a subscription to the method `clearFilter_onClick`

Answer (score 3):

To clear a filter on a DataView, set its RowFilter property to an empty string

```
 yourDataView.DefaultView.RowFilter = ""
```